# why does css, bootstrap code break sometime

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

There are two tabs (`tab-one`, `tab-two`) I am working on - one is visible, second is hidden. Sometimes code breaks between the bottom of `tab-one` and the top of `tab-two` - some portion of `tab-two` is visible, sometimes.

#### Below is the actual code usually works properly

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="tab-one">
        <div class="form-group reg-form-group-mar">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 reg-form-col-6">
                    <div class="reg-lab-hi">
                        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="firstname" class="form-control input-title firstname" id="firstname" name="firstname">
                    <div class="reg-err"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <div class="reg-lab-hi"><label for="lastname">Last Name</label></div>
                    <input type="lastname" class="form-control input-title lastname" id="email" name="email" >
                    <div class="reg-err"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="tab-two display-none">
        <div class="form-group reg-form-group-mar">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 reg-form-col-6">
                    <div class="reg-lab-hi">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-title email" id="email" name="email">
                    <div class="reg-err"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <div class="reg-lab-hi"><label for="password">Password</label></div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-title password" id="password" name="password">
                    <div class="reg-err"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### And this is how the code breaks sometimes

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="tab-one">
        <div class="form-group reg-form-group-mar">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 reg-form-col-6">
                    <div class="reg-lab-hi">
                        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="firstname" class="form-control input-title firstname" id="firstname" name="firstname">
                    <div class="reg-err"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <div class="reg-lab-hi"><label for="lastname">Last Name</label></div>
                    <input type="lastname" class="form-control input-title lastname" id="lastname" name="lastname">
                        
                        <!-- {{ code breaks here }} -->
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-title first-name" id="email" name="email">
                    <div class="reg-err"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <div class="reg-lab-hi"><label for="email">Password</label></div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-title password" id="password" name="password">
                    <div class="reg-err"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using custom jQuery to show/hide tabs.  I tried to put bootstrap link before my own css and vice versa; Also, I've tried to puting Javascript at the bottom of `body` and at the bottom of `head` tags; but, nothing works.

Any suggestion regarding this?

Comment: Instead of using display-none.
use fade in or fade class.

To show use class= 'fade in '
To hide use class ='fade'

how this way it will work.

Comment: i thinks this is not occurring because of display-none; as the code is breaking from tab-one and it escape some portion of tab-two(display-none also), thats why it is visible.
The issue is why code breaks in tab-one

Comment: unless I messed up something during my editing, you're trying to show the difference between having 2 tabs with bootstrap vs 1 tab, where the 1 tab causes the styling issue to be observed, right?

Comment: you may be missing some important tags and styles here to reproduce the issue for us in run.. the controls should be a in a `form` (in regards to `form-control` usage); it's difficult to tell what issue you're actually observing in that respect.

Comment: also, in your second example code - is the lack of `div class="reg-lab-hi"` around the email `label` a typo, or is a potential cause here?

Comment: "you may be missing some important tags and styles here", most of the time the code works properly and sometime don't. I also make some changes in bootstrap's default form-control, but i thinks i did not effect because I tested the code by removing this form-control

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code found that there are issue with the order of div and input type. 
Please update the below html code with yours and it will work fine.

```
<div class="tab-one">
    <div class="form-group reg-form-group-mar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 reg-form-col-6">
                <div class="reg-lab-hi">
                    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                </div>
                <input type="firstname" class="form-control input-title firstname" id="firstname" name="firstname">
                <div class="reg-err"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
                <div class="reg-lab-hi"><label for="lastname">Last Name</label></div>
                <input type="lastname" class="form-control input-title lastname" id="lastname" name="lastname">

            </div>

            <div class="reg-err"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="reg-lab-hi"><label for="email">Email</label></div>

                <input type="email" class="form-control input-title first-name" id="email" name="email">

                <div class="reg-err"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
                <div class="reg-lab-hi"><label for="email">Password</label></div>
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-title password" id="password" name="password">
                <div class="reg-err"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** 
To use bootstrap them make sure each container has properly assigned.

Comment: @Brett Caswell Please suggest me if it answer to the main question or not :)

Comment: it's difficult for me to determine that myself. the OP will have to clarify whether the second code sample's missing `div` around the `label for="email"`was an aspect of the issue or a mistake in presenting the sample to us.

Answer (score 0):

If want the tab option then go for the below example.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
    </div>
```

Make sure you have added the jquery.min.js,  bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js files..

This way you won't need to write any additional logic to keep it show and hide.

Comment: I'm not sure suggesting an alternative here is warranted given the problem is specific to the code provided.  determining what the issue is still undetermined on at the moment, but it is related to bootstrap ui margin and hierarchical semantics I would bet.

Comment: having said that, it is a good alternative.  certainly helpful